# Javascript: is it safe to "throw undefined"?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

In the function below, when the condition fails I want the situation to be handled as a simple error (no details needed). Just out of curiosity, is it OK and safe to write `throw undefined`?

```
function splitYearMonth (YM) { // Returns ["yyyy-mm", yyyy, mm]
  try {
    var o = YM.match(/^(\d{4})\-(0[1-9]|1[012])$/);
    if (o != null) {
      return  [o[0], parseInt(o[1], 10), parseInt(o[2], 10)];
    } else {
      throw undefined;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return [undefined, undefined, undefined];
  }
}
```

Comment: Never mind the example given. Basically my (idle) question is just: I don't care about the error I'm throwing, I'm tempted to throw `undefined` because it seems to make more sense that any other type of specific value, and I want to know if that's safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to do so.

The ECMAScript 5.1 specification [says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.13):

> The production *ThrowStatement* : **throw** [no *LineTerminator* here]
>   *Expression ;* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *exprRef* be the result of evaluating *Expression*.
> 2. Return (throw, GetValue(*exprRef*), empty).

ECMAScript 6 [uses the same terms](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-throw-statement).

`undefined` is definitely an expression, so it can be thrown. You can see an example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uL8ur01h/).

That said, throwing `undefined` may not be a good idea from a maintainability standpoint, because doing so leaves you with no information at all about the cause of the exception. Throwing a string would arguably be a better solution:

```
var o = YM.match(/^(\d{4})\-(0[1-9]|1[012])$/);
if (o != null) {
    return [o[0], parseInt(o[1], 10), parseInt(o[2], 10)];
} else {
    throw "unrecognized date format";
}
```

---

***Update:*** On second thought, unless the *no details needed* clause in your question means you're not telling us the whole story, you only need control flow, not exception handling. You only have to write:

```
function splitYearMonth(YM) {  // Returns ["yyyy-mm", yyyy, mm]
    var o = YM.match(/^(\d{4})\-(0[1-9]|1[012])$/);
    if (o != null) {
        return [o[0], parseInt(o[1], 10), parseInt(o[2], 10)];
    } else {
        return [undefined, undefined, undefined];
    }
}
```

Exception handling can be expensive, and it is usually not recommended to use this facility for control flow (since we're discussing Javascript and not, say, Python).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of throw is:

```
throw expression;
```

As `undefined` is a valid expression, it is safe to do this, although it is generally good practice to return a sensible error message, for example:

```
throw "Failed to split year and month for the given input"
```